# send multiple messages in android

Tags: android, message

i want to send messages to five different numbers.  I am getting that numbers from an another page by using the getIntent() method. Can anyone please give a proper way to send the messages. i used the following code. but it toasts that " SMS sent fo first number" and then all other messages are getting failed.!!  But the thing is that i didnt even recieve any message.!!

```
try{
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage( phonenumber1 ,null,message,null, null);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to First   Number.!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}catch(Exception e)
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent failed to First Number.!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
e.printStackTrace();

} // like this up to phonenumber5 with the same try and catch block each five times
```

Comment: If your message is more than 1 message then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774009/broadcast-receiver-with-sendmultiparttextmessage

Comment: What name.?? are you saying.?

Comment: Ok. i got it.!! But i have no idea to which code that i haev to take and put. please help me out. Suggest me the correct code.?? from that example

Comment: How are you sending numbers through intent? In a string array?

Comment: refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771470/android-send-sms-to-multiple-contacts-using-arraylist

Comment: Am getting numbers in five different strings.  and then it put into the above sending message code. thats why used five different try and catch block for sending the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. Firstly, put all numbers in a string array, and use for loop instead of 5 try catch.

```
String receipentsNumber[] = {"111","222","333","444","555"};

for (int i = 0; i < receipentsNumber.length; i++) {

try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(receipentsNumber[i], null, message, null,
                    null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to" + " " + receipentsNumber[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

As you get success for first number, I presume you have added permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. I will check it out and will tell you surely.

Comment: Please look at my other questions.!!

Comment: Go to this link ->     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058532/wait-for-the-process-to-finish-to-start-another-process

Answer (score 0):

5 try catches is not a good method. Why not put all numbers in a string array, and use for loop instead of 5 try catch