# wait for the process to finish to start another process

Tags: android, function, email, sms

When the user clicks on my button, it performs two functions: sending an SMS and sending an email.

When I click on this button, the SMS is being sent and suddenly the email choose client window pop ups. I want the email client chooser window to show only after completing the SMS sending function.

How should I change my code?

```
     Button hi= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     hi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendsms();
            sendemail();
     } 

     private void sendemail() {

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to1});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to2});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to3});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to4});
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to5});

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailmessage);

        //need this to prompts email client only
        email.setType("message/rfc822");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));


    }


    sendsms()
    {
        String receipentsNumber[] = {"111","222","333","444","555"};

        for (int i = 0; i < receipentsNumber.length; i++) {

            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(receipentsNumber[i], null, message, null,
                        null);
                System.ot.println(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to" + " " + receipentsNumber[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Call `sendMail()` after `for loop` of `sendSMS()`